# How to prevent an image from scaling outside parent's borders?

Tags: css, html

I have list of different services provided, each service has an image, heading, and description. I've set it up so that image scales to 1.3x size on mouse hover. The scaling works, but it ignores the parent's borders when doing so.

I've captured a GIF of what it looks like in action.

[image: Example of image scaling outside of parent's borders]

Here is the code I'm working with.

```css
.cleaningservices {
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;

}

    /* Default state of the image */
    .hover01 img {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      transform: scale(1);
      -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    }

    /* Scale the image to 1.3 it's size on mouse hover */
    .hover01:hover img {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
      transform: scale(1.3);
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="cleaningservices">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail hover01">
        <img src="https://bosworthco.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/cleaning-268134_960_720.jpg" alt="deep house cleaning">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Deep Cleaning</h3>
          <p>Usually, on our first visit we will most likely have to complete a deep cleaning. It is a far more intensive cleaning that our regular cleaning. After first deep cleaning we will continue with one of our regularly scheduled cleanings below.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What changes do I have to make to make the images scale inside the parent's borders on mouse hover?

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` on parent?

Comment: Reduce the scaling factor.

Comment: Give overflow: hidden; to the parent.

Comment: As everyone says about, overflow hidden will sort you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could add the image to a div and give the div `overflow:hidden;`

```css
.hover01 img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    width:100%;
}
.hover01:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

.img-parent{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
   <div class="cleaningservices">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
   <div class="thumbnail hover01">
      <div class="img-parent">
         <img src="http://fiusms.fiu.edu/wp-content/uploads/Residential-Cleaning-Watauga-TX.jpg" alt="deep house cleaning">
             </div>
      <div class="caption">
  <h3>Deep Cleaning</h3>
  <p>Usually, on our first visit we will most likely have to complete a deep cleaning. It is a far more intensive cleaning that our regular cleaning. After first deep cleaning we will continue with one of our regularly scheduled cleanings below.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably the cleanest way to do it since it also avoids zooming over the subsequent text. I'd call the class `.noverflow`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it indeed helped me achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Create an img container on which you set `overflow: hidden;`. I added a background-color on `body` so you see it works.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0 !important;
  padding: 50px;
}
.noverflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.hover01 img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover01:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cleaningservices">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail hover01">
        <div class="noverflow"><img src="http://fiusms.fiu.edu/wp-content/uploads/Residential-Cleaning-Watauga-TX.jpg" alt="deep house cleaning"></div>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Deep Cleaning</h3>
          <p>Usually, on our first visit we will most likely have to complete a deep cleaning. It is a far more intensive cleaning that our regular cleaning. After first deep cleaning we will continue with one of our regularly scheduled cleanings below.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `overflow: hidden;`

```
.hover01 img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```